# simplexml loop, loop count good data bad

Tags: php, xml, loops, simplexml

Trying my first  simplexml loop

I have got to this:

```
foreach ($xml->GetCapabilityResponse->Srvs->Srv as $rows)
{
echo $xml->GetCapabilityResponse->Srvs->Srv->GlobalProductCode . " ";
echo  $xml->GetCapabilityResponse->Srvs->Srv->MrkSrv->LocalProductCode . " " ; 
echo  $xml->GetCapabilityResponse->Srvs->Srv->MrkSrv->ProductShortName . "<br>";
}
```

It returns the correct amount of rows '6' but all 6 are the same data from the first row, how do I adjust to show the 6 different rows own data, it's not limited to 6, could be 12 or more etc

thanks
Mazz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if $rows is an array, you should rely on the item you are processing

```
$row->GlobalProductCode . " ";
```

Comment: perfect, can't see the wood for the trees